# Need help with network configuration

Tags: networking

Without much knowledge I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm having trouble setting up the network. After configuring the ipv4 settings and mac address and clicking save nothing happened and when I went back to the settings the mac address wasn't the one I set. No matter how many times I try to set it it just goes back to the previous one.

Comment: Are you doing this through network-manager?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it trough the network manager.

Comment: Did you change the Method option from "Automatic" to "Manual"

Comment: I did, otherwise it wouldn't let me type in anything in there.

Comment: edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, and change the line "managed=false" to "managed=true"

Comment: @CharlesGreen Every time I change the settings this happens - http://i.imgur.com/2z2BQQf.png also clicking on options after that gives me an error.

Comment: Why are you cloning MAC? Just wanted to say that it's not typical unless your ISP is bound by your MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you are setting `Cloned MAC address` and not `Device MAC address`.

[image: interface mac clone]